# Мощи и мощь - что общего?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Мощь - понятно, сила, могущество. Мощи - останки святых, почитаемые как реликвии. Так вот, меня интересует, что ли связь между этими словами? И еще в эту же кучу хочется добавить слово "изможденный", мне кажется, оно родственное слову "мощи". Но родственно ли оно при этом слову "мощь", являясь по смыслу его противоположностью?
То есть, "мощи" и "мощь", "мощный" являются ли родственными словами?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Этимологический словарь Крылова
>
> **МОЩИ**
>
> Это название останков человека, почитаемого святым, было заимствовано из старославянского, в котором образовано от **мошть** – "сила". Буквально слово мощи значит "мощные силы, творящие чудеса".

Если при жизни человека называли просто *мощным* :

> Илья Ильф, Евгений Петров. Двенадцать стульев (1927)
> Остап показал рукой на Воробьянинова. ― Кто, по-вашему, **этот мощный старик?** Не говорите, вы не можете этого знать.

... то после смерти великого святого вполне логично было приписать *мощность* его нетленным костям-останкам. Вера, как известно, буквально творит чудеса.
Впоследствии слово приобрело также некоторый иронический оттенок, намекающий на откровенную худобу : *девушка стройна - мы скажем : мощи...*

*Изможденный* - не имеет отношения к *мощи*, скорее, он родственник *промозглости*...